# "Left a X on here above."

Tags: phrase-usage

Example:

> He began descending the cliff. I watched as, inch by inch, he vanished
>   into the darkness below and **left a waving rope on here above.**

I have doubts about the phrase because it sounds a bit odd, and got [not results](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&q=%22left+a+*+here+above%22&oq=%22left+a+*+here+above%22&gs_l=serp.12...189563.189719.0.190873.4.3.0.0.0.0.174.174.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..4.0.0.b0Pd7bJjwRI) on Google.

Is it common to say *leaving a/an X here/there above*? If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: As an alternative : "leaving behind a hanging rope"

Comment: '*On* here above' (as in your example) sounds even stranger than 'here above' (as in your question). About which are you really asking?

Comment: What is the source of that quote??

Comment: 'On here above' is not grammatical. I suspect an OCR error. Do you have a link to the source?

Comment: I wrote the passage, so the source is me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better alternative would be:

> ... he vanished into the darkness below, and left a dangling rope behind him
>   OR
>   He began descending the cliff. …, and left a rope dangling [high] above him.

**[dangle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dangle)**: hanging or swinging loosely.
Oxford Dictionaries suggests this very apt example sentence.

> From the long tapering fingers of her right hand **a golden chain dangled** and swinging idly from its end hung a small iridescent vial.

Answer (score 1):

Above seems to have been used to contrast "below" which modifies the darkness as an adverb.

A rope is above while the darkness is below.

Here can be both "noun" and "adverb". Therefore, it is not ungrammatical to use a preposition "on" before here.

He is not in here. = He is not here.
He is there. = He is in there.

I think the above sentence is quoted from a novel and the sentence is in line with a writer's stylistic sense.

It doesn't read "odd" to me.

Hope it helps.